# G(k,X) is a modular form of weight k and character X

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, fourier-series, modular-forms, poisson-summation-formula

I'm trying to proof the transformation property of the Eisenstein series G(k,X) defined on page 17: https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.1007/978-3-540-74119-0_1/fulltext.pdf

I already tried to compute the fourier coefficients of the transformed series,but it didn't work. An other idea I had was to use poisson summation formula, but there I can't find a fitting schwartz function. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Poisson summation is valid for some functions that are not necessarily Schwartz functions.